# Sum up values present in vertical Dataframe in Horizontal DataFrame and create new column in Horizontal Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having dataframe `idf` as below. I have another Dataframe `df`

```
idf

Output-

       feature_name idf_weights
2488    kralendijk  11.221923
3059    night       11.221923
1383    ebebf       11.221923
```

```
df

Output-

     message                   Number of Words in each message
0   night kralendijk ebebf          3
```

I want to add 'idf weights' from idf dataframe for each word in "df" dataframe in new column.

Output will look like below-

```
df

Output-

     message                   Number of Words in each message   IDF Score 
0   night kralendijk ebebf                 3                     33.665769
```

I tried summing up in below code but it's not working.

Code-

```
df["Total_IDF Score"] = idf['idf_weights'].sum(axis=0)
```

Thank you.

Comment: [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the word [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the column. `merge` with idf sum over the idf_weights would be a possible way

Comment: What means ` it's not working.` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to convert idf to a dictionary first, like that:

```
words_weights = dict(idf[['feature_name', 'idf_weights']].values)

{'kralendijk': 11.221923, 'night': 11.221923, 'ebebf': 11.221923}
```

then just split the message col, get corresponding value for each word from dict and sum it up:

```
df['score'] = df['message'].apply(lambda x: sum([words_weights.get(word, 0) for word in x.split()]))
```

Comment: Your Solution worked, Thanks!!!

I am not tried to count the number of words present in the message which is having idf_weights > 0. I used counts to calculate words with non-zero idf_weights but I am getting total count of words instead of only the non-zero count of words.

Code-


df['> zero'] = df['message'].apply(lambda x: count([words_weights.get(word, 0) for word in x.split()]))